# Why do parsing errors keep occurring in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parsing, npm, terminal

So I am building a website with React and when I'm writing some code, every now and then an error message appears: `Parsing error: Unexpected token`.

So I did `^c` in the terminal to exit the program and did `npm start` to run the program again. Then, the error message disappears.

Does anyone know a fix to this issue?

[Here is an example screenshot code that's giving me a Parsing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyd6U.png)

```
<Link to={subqueue.link}>
     <div className={(this.state.subqueue === subqueue.id) ? "ssbSQItem active" : "ssbSQItem"}>
         <div className={'ssbSQItemTitle ' + ((subqueue.count === null) && 'fluid')}>{subqueue.title}</div>
     </div>
</Link>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should use the `{}` button to add code to your question. It would make it easier to understand your code.

Comment: It sounds like there is an issue with your build or what ever you are running.

Comment: @epascarello I think so too. Do you know how to fix this?